# Do applets and the browser share a cache?

Tags: file, applet, flash, external, shared

I have a third party applet that makes use a csv file, let's call it `file.csv`, and makes use of all of the columns. I also have a third party swf object that makes use of `file.csv` but only makes use of 20% of the columns. The initial decision was to use the same file for both because it would result in easier maintenance.

My question is, does `file.csv` get downloaded by the browser once and get shared by both the applet and the swf OR are both the applet and the swf downloading their own copy of `file.csv`?

This is important because `file.csv` is a large file and if the user has to download it twice, there would be a bandwidth savings in maintaining two versions.

Using Firebug, the CSV is only listed once. However, when I remove the swf, the applet still fetches `file.csv` but it is not listed in Firebug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question, but further investigation revealed that the applet and the browser were both downloading the file independently.